# jsdoc-toolkit doesn't like my syntax?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I'm using jsdoc for the first time and it doesn't seem to like a bit of my syntax and I can't find anything it does like:

```
(function(){  // issue #1
    /**
     * Creates an instance of a Cube animation
     * @class
     */
    function Cube(x, y, z){
       ...
    }

    /** @lends Cube.prototype */
    cubeFrame.prototype = { // Issue #2
       ...
    }
})();
```

Issue #1: For some reason I get an error of "WARNING: Trying to document ***someMethod*** as a member of undocumented symbol Cube." if I leave that wrapping function in.  If I comment it out, it works.

Issue #2: I'm doing something a bit odd with my classes and can't figure out a way to get jsDoc to pay attention when I say `@lends Cube.prototype` in terms of applying the following object to `Cube` and not `cubeFrame`.  I get a nearly identical error to #1: " WARNING: Trying to document getVoxel as a member of undocumented symbol ***cubeFrame***.".  I don't want `cubeFrame` to be documentated, I want its prototypes to go into the `Cube` documentation.

I can re-write those two lines and get the documentation to generate (it's then invalid code), but I don't want to have to re-write code to generate documentation every time I make a change!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `@name` tag to let jsdoc know the name of the object, then name of the class and replace the `@lends` tag to right prior to the object literal. Like:

```
(function(){
    /**
     * Creates an instance of a Cube animation
     * @class
     * @name Cube
     */
    function Cube(){
       //...
    }
    cubeFrame.prototype = /** @lends Cube.prototype */{ // Issue #2
       //...
       /**
       */
       someMethod: function(){}
    };
})()
```

Comment: One question - why is `@name` required here?

Comment: Since `Cube`is defined inside a function(in this case an anonymous one it tries do document `Cube` "inside"(can't remember the notation), them the `@name Cude` causes it to be properly documented.

Comment: As Prusse correctly says, the name (meaning the full globally-defined variable name) of the "Cube" function can't be found by JSDoc because it's defined as an inner function inside the scope of an anonymous function. So, from outside that anonymous function, there is no way to access the thing called "Cube". The `@name` tag tells JSDoc that you wish to document that function as if it had a *global* name of "Cube", that is as if it were defined & accessed as `window.Cube` in a browser. It's just confusing that the documented global name and the actual inner name happen to be the same word.